# Android-studio: table layouts conten reformats when text is cahnged

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, kotlin

So I have a table layout like this:
[image: table layout]

[XML](https://haste.thevillage.chat/owijewiwos.xml)

So the problem is, it looks good on first start, but after changing the text it looks ugly and completly resized. I tried using percnet for the width, but it failed.
So how can I make it not resizing when changing the text?

Comment: I am not sure it's the solution but it worth trying.  in your XML some of your TextVIew Width is set to wrap content which changes the size according to the text inside of it.  try change it to something less dynamic like a dp.

Comment: i'll write it as an answer for future dev to see. mark it as accepted please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML some f your TextViews Width is set to "Wrap content" which changes the size according to the length of the text it holds. Change it to something less dynamic like `dp` for example.